# Retrieve Count of Grouped Items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the count of certain results for a query based on the grouped items. I have this query:

```
SELECT c.name FROM tblCareers AS cc
INNER JOIN tblClusters AS c
ON c.careerid = cc.careerid
INNER JOIN @temp AS t
ON cc.userid = CurrentID
```

This gives me the results:

```
Agriculture
Healthcare
Agriculture
```

What I want to be able to return is:

```
Agriculture 2
Healthcare 1
```

So I need some sort of Count(c.name) but that just returns:

```
Agriculture 1
Healthcare 1
Agriculture 1
```

Any suggestions or how to?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT c.name, Count(*) FROM tblCareers AS cc
LEFTJOIN tblClusters AS c
ON c.careerid = cc.careerid
LEFT JOIN @temp AS t
ON cc.userid = CurrentID
Group by c.name
order by Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: What about trying to get all the career names regardless of whether or not a user was in that career: Something like Agriculture 3, Healthcare 2, Information Technology 0 <-- the above query would omit the Information Technology because no users are part of that career. Any ideas for that. Other than that the counting seems to work just fine.

Comment: all that does is reorder the list so Agriculture is 2 at the top and Healthcare is 1 at the bottom but still no Information Technology which is in the tblCareers table